# How to report the average measurement?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, error-analysis

> Average Length is calculated from 40 measurements as 9582[cm]; but the standard deviation is σ=800[cm]. What is the proper way to report the average measurement?

I'm not sure if this is reported via variables or how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The average is reported as the mean (average) $\pm$ the Standard Error in the Mean (SE), which is $\sigma / \sqrt{N}$ where $N$ is the number of measurements.